# Find the term with the lowest 2nd argument, in a list, with Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a list like this:

```
L = [range(2,3), range(5,6), range(10,9), range(-2,-30), range(-5,-30)]
```

Now, I need to make the term `range(-5,-30)` the first element of this list, because it's the term with the lowest `Y`, in the case that 2 terms has the lowest `Y`, I'll choose the one with the lowest `X`.

I don't know how to do it with Prolog, I tried something like:

```
find_n_make_first([F,S|T]) :-
 F =.. [_,Fx,Fy],
 S =.. [_,Sx,Sy],
 (   Sy<Fy ->
 find_n_make_first([S,F|T])
 ;   Fy<Sy ->
 find_n_make_first([F,S|T])
 ;   Fy = Sy ->
 (   Sx<Fx ->
 find_n_make_first([S,F|T])
 ;   Fx<Sx ->
 find_n_make_first([F,S|T])
 )
 ).
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: Start with examples! It is not completely clear what you want!

Comment: I want a predicate that makes the term range(X,Y) with the lowest Y (in case of equality, the one with the lowest X) the first element of the list L, because I need to apply the Graham Scan algorithm, and the first thing to do is to take the term with the lowest Y (in case of equality, the lowest X), and make it the first term of the list. Is it more clear now ?

Comment: Give **concrete** examples how you would use it on the toplevel!

Comment: I read a csv file from local folder, then i used the term csv_read_file to read the csv file and make facts. Now I have a List with all these facts, and the Graham Scan's algorithm require to have the list with the term with lowest Y at the first position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your first problem is to understand how such a definition would be used. Always start with **imagining** that you have already a working definition. You will learn there the most important part about relations: In relations there are no implicit "return values". You need to define them separately. So in your case this would be:

```
?- list_sortedby2([range(2,3),range(10,9),range(-2,-30),range(-5,-30)], Us).
   Us = [range(-5,-30),range(-2,-30),range(2,3),range(10,9)].
```

Only **then** start to define it!

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

list_sortedby2(Ts, Us) :-
   must_be_ground(Ts),
   maplist(\T^(A2+T)^arg(2,T,A2), Ts, A2Ts), % or map1(Ts, A2Ts)
   sort(A2Ts, A2Us),
   maplist(\ (_+U)^U^true, A2Us, Us).        % or map2(A2Us, Us)

must_be_ground(Ss) :-
   ( ground(Ss) -> true
   ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_))
   ).
```

In place of `maplist/3` and λ, you could also write manually:

```
map1([], []).
map1([T|Ts], [A2+T|A2Ts]) :-
   arg(2, T, A2),
   map1(Ts, A2Ts).

map2([], []).
map2([_+U|A2Us], [U|Us]) :-
   map2(A2Us, Us).
```

---

With an afterthought, there is something else: Better replace the goal `arg(2, T, A2)` by `( T = range(_, A2) )`, since you are only interested in structures `range/2`. In this manner, `list_sortedby2([f(1,2)], Us)` fails which is a much safer way to handle an unexpected case. (It would be even safer to produce a type error, but at least it does not succeed.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, can I ask another question about this project ?

Comment: Checked, now I should create a new question or just write it here ? (sorry but I'm new to this platform)

Comment: @MoksudAhmed: New question!